# mistakes in analogous puzzles from The Tipping Point

Tags: logical-deduction, explanation

In the book 'The Tipping Point', Malcolm Gladwell cites two puzzles and draws an analogy between them, in fact he claims the two are equivalent. I believe there are some problems with both puzzles, and the analogy as well. Do you see the same problems, and are there any suggestions to fix this?

The first riddle:

> Consider the following brain teaser. Suppose I give you four cards,
>   labeled with the letter A and D and the numerals 3 and 6. The rule of
>   the game is that a card with a vowel on it always has an even number
>   on the other side. Which of the cards would you have to turn over to
>   prove this rule to be true? The answer is two: the A card and the
>   three card. The overwhelming majority of the people given this test,
>   though, don't get it right. They tend to answer just the A card, or
>   the A and the 6. It's a hard question.

Here, the `D`-card should be turned over as well, as there is no indication that cards cannot have letters on both sides.

And now the second:

> But now let me pose another question. Suppose four people are drinking
>   in a bar. One is drinking Coke. One is sixteen. One is drinking beer
>   and one is twenty-five. Given the rule that no one under twenty-one is
>   allowed to drink beer, which of those people's IDs do we have to check
>   to make sure the law is being observed? Now the answer is easy, in
>   fact, I'm sure that almost everyone will get it right: The
>   beer-drinker and the sixteen-year-old. But, as the psychologist Leda
>   Cosmides (who dreamt up this example) points out, it is exactly the
>   same puzzle as the A, D, 3 and 6 puzzle. The difference is that it is
>   framed in a way that makes it about people, instead of about numbers,
>   and as human beings we are a lot more sophisticated about each other
>   than we are about the abstract world.

But checking the ID of the sixteen-year-old doesn't make sense, you already know his age. He can still be drinking tequila while you read his birth-date.

The analogy is incorrect after these mistakes. If those two mistakes are fixed, by adding the rule 'Cards always have a letter on one side and a number on the other' to the first puzzle, and in the second case alter the wording so that we may also check the drink of the sixteen-year-old, the analogy is correct, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Those mistakes should be fixed in order to make the questions analogous.

Answer (score 2):

The second riddle seems to be badly worded.
The first one is correct as it is, though.
In order to check that a card with a vowel on one side always has an even number on the other side you have to check two cards. The first one is obvious: in case the A card doesn't have an even number on the other side the rule is proven wrong. Then you have to check the "3" card for pretty much the same reason: if there is a vowel on the other side the rule is proven wrong again. Checking the remaining two cards is useless as there is not a rule saying what's on the other side of a consonant - D - or what's on the other side of an even number - 6. Remember that there is only one rule: if a card has a vowel on one side there must be an even number on the other side. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the objection to the first riddle. Suppose the card with a D visible had an E on the other side. Then the rule "a card with a vowel on it always has an even number on the other side" is violated, because the card with an E on one side has a D on the other side. The proposed fix is to specify that all cards have a letter in one side and a number on the other, which would prevent this scenario.

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks! :)